# How to configure Simple Spring Memcached to work with Couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, memcached, couchbase, simple-spring-memcached

I'm developing a Spring MVC application, and I'd like to set up caching using [Simple Spring Memcached](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/) (SSM) with a Couchbase backend.

I have setup a working couchbase install locally, with a memcache bucket "default".  I can connect and use the Couchbase Java API in a test project.

However, when using the SSM annotations within my Spring MVC project I get timeout exceptions.  I'm fairly confident that the issue lies with my SSM configuration:

```
<bean name="defaultMemcachedClient" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
    <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean name="cacheClientFactory" class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.spymemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
    </property>
    <property name="addressProvider">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
            <property name="address" value="127.0.0.1:8091" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Notice it makes no mention of the "default" bucket, or of any authentication parameters.
I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to configure SSM to work with specific couchbase buckets in this way.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using the SSM (Memcached) you need to connect to the memcached port, which is 11211 instead of 8091.

Comment: Port 8091 is the admin/config port, you can get cluster configuration from that port (http).

Port 8092 is for Map/Reduce View querying (http).

Port 11211 is the memcached port for binary operations (binary socket).

Comment: Thanks scalabl3.  That fixed the problem.  Looks like I need a more thorough read through of the couchbase docs.

Comment: No problem! Hit me up anytime on twitter if you need anything else that doesn't fit into an SO question @scalabl3